# How does array name represent different values when switching %p form %s in printf in C

Tags: arrays, c, printf

I couldn't understand how array name, which points to the first address of the array, can represent a value if used with %s in printf.
When used with %p, array name would represent the address, which is what I predicted. However, when used with %s, the array name would represent the value. I thought I would have to dereference the array name using * to refer to the value in that address?

```
// How can an array name represent different values when we just change the argument from %s to %d?
    //====== array =======
    char name1[10] = "name1";
    printf("%s \n", name1); // prints name1
    printf("%p \n", name1); // prints address

    //====== malloc =======
    char* name2 = (char*)malloc(10);
    strcpy(name2, "name2"); 
    printf("%s \n", name2); // prints name2
    printf("%p", name2); // prints address
```

Comment: `%s` considers the argument value to be the address of a string, reads the string stored after that address, and outputs the string. That is all.

Comment: You are not using `%d`, you are using `%p`.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the array address<sup>1</sup> is passed to `printf`.

`%s` tells `printf` to read the memory at that address and print the characters it finds there until it finds a null character.

`%p` tells `printf` to print the address in some human-readable way. (The specific format used is implementation-defined; it may vary across different C implementations.)

(Properly, when using `%p`, the address ought to be converted to `void *`: `printf("%p \n", (void *) name1);`. Although the behavior is not defined by the C standard if this is not done, it will work in most C implementations.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> In `printf("%s \n", name1);`, the array `name1` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This automatic conversion occurs whenever an array is used in an expression except as the operand of `sizeof`, as the operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array.

Answer (score 1):

Both specifiers, `%p` and `%s`, expect a pointer value.

> I thought I would have to dereference the array name using * to refer to the value in that address?

That is what `printf` is doing for you, when using the `%s` specifier.

`printf` reads the specifier `%s`, and gets the associated [variadic argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) as a `char *`. Using this pointer value, it performs [indirection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) - printing the character value pointed at, and incrementing the pointer until said character value is equal to the null terminating character.

*Very* crudely, this looks like:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_a_string(const char *str)
{
    while (*str)
        putchar(*str++);
}

void print(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    while (*fmt) {
        if ('%' == *fmt) {
            fmt++;

            if (!*fmt)
                break;

            if ('s' == *fmt)
                print_a_string(va_arg(args, char *));
        } else
            putchar(*fmt);

        fmt++;
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *string = "Hello world!";

    print("%s\n", string);
}
```

---

The `%p` specifier produces an implementation defined character sequence that represents a pointer value.

Also note that an argument associated with the `%p` specifier should be cast to a `void *`.

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) name1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I thought I would have to dereference the array name using * to refer to the value in that address?*

The `printf` function does that, internally.

```
printf("%s\n", "hello");
```

is similar to

```
puts("hello");
```

In neither case do you see the `*` operator: just the address of the first character is passed into the function. The `puts` function could look like:

```
int puts(const char *str)
{
  while (*str) {
    if (putchar(*str++) == EOF)  // The * operator is here!
      return EOF;
  }
  if (putchar('\n') == EOF)
    return EOF;
  return 0;
}
```

A function which receives a pointer to an object may use the `*` operator to retrieve value(s) from that object, so the value extraction isn't visible in the function call.